# Which of the following vectors are in ker(T)?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let *T: R2→R2* be the linear operator given by the formula:
*T(x,y) = (2x-y, -8x+4y)*

Which of the following vectors are in ker(T)?

*Note that ker(T) is the kernel of T. The way I *think* I should approach this problem is to plug in the given vectors and see if I get 0 as an answer. For example, for part a I would say:

T(5, 10) = [(2(5)-10), -8(5)+4(10)] = (0,0).

Thus, the vector of (5,10) would be in ker(T), right? I don't need answers to each of the following. I just need to be sure I'm approaching the problem correctly. Could someone confirm?

**a)**  (5,10)
**b)**  (3,2)
**c)**  (1,1)

Comment: Yes, just plug them in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that’s the most straightforward way to answer the question, and it works fine. You can also note that $-8x+4y=(-4)(2x-y)$, so any values of $x$ and $y$ that make $2x-y=0$ also make $-8x+4y=0$. Thus, $\ker T$ is precisely the set of vectors $\langle x,y\rangle$ such that $2x-y=0$, or $y=2x$. Geometrically it’s the line of slope $2$ through the origin. This is overkill for this specific problem, but if you had a longer list of vectors to test for membership in $\ker T$, it would save you some work.